# Nant build script IDE

Tags: ide, nant, build-script

I work on project where is huge Nant build script.
Could you advise free Nant build script IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using NAnt, I'm going to assume you're working in Visual Studio. Since the build file is just XML, you can tell Visual Studio to use the [NAnt schema](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.91/nant.xsd) and you'll get what you're looking for looking for.

As per @TheChairman's comment, you'll even get Intellisense.

Comment: My recommendation too. With the 'nant.xsd' in your 'schemas' directory you'll even get Intellisense

Comment: Unfortunately nothing better for now, I can not find :-(

Answer (score 1):

After wikipedia:

NAntGUI an open source tool for editing and running NAnt scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at NantBuilder. It has powerful IDE.

http://www.polestarsoft.com/products/nantbuilder